# Control the verbosity of Flask's tests

Tags: python, flask

I'm running tests for my Flask app from Bash using `python manage.py test`. In addition to failures and errors, the console prints out

```
    test_name (test_file.TestClass) ... ok
```

for every single test. That's super annoying when you have a lot of tests. How can I control the verbosity of the printout?

Comment: It's standard `unittest`, I think, so you can only turn *up* the verbosity: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-v

Comment: There's something going on in manage.py that keeps normal methods from working. Running `python manage.py test -v` gives "manage.py: error: too many arguments"

Comment: Wait, *Flask* `manage.py`? I was thinking Django. Are you using some plugin, I don't think that's standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jonrsharpe was right. I didn't realize that the project was using Flask-Script, which I guess is the reason for the manage.py file. Flask-Script calls unittest with a default verbosity. I reduced the default verbosity and that culled the extra output.